# SQL Server 2005 Insert with Foreign Key conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I looked at several other posts with this general title and couldn't figure out an answer to this question. I have two tables, "exam" and "hold". I've inserted two rows into the "exam" table (primary key "accession") and for each row I've attempted to insert a key into the "hold" table, using SQL Server Management Studio. I see the data in the "exam" table, with a value in the "accession" field; but I'm not able to insert corresponding values into the "hold" table.

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[exam](
    [accession] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MRN] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [serviceDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [modality] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [billedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [billingFile] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [message] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__exam__1ED998B2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [accession] ASC
)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hold](
    [accession] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [reason] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [held] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [resolved] [datetime] NULL
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[hold]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__hold__accession__20C1E124] FOREIGN KEY([accession])
REFERENCES [dbo].[exam] ([accession])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[hold] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__hold__accession__20C1E124]
```

And here's what I tried to insert:

```
begin tran
    insert into exam
    (accession,mrn,servicedate,location,modality)
    values
    ('RAM1093129','RAM3202911','2014-03-05 10:06:52','HAM','CR')
    insert into exam
    (accession,mrn,servicedate,location,modality)
    values
    ('RAM1093130','RAM3202911','2014-03-05 10:04:49','HAM','CR')
commit

begin tran
    insert into hold
    (accession,held,reason)
    values
    ('1093129',getdate(),'Sue - check insurance')
    insert into hold
    (accession,held,reason)
    values
    ('1093130',getdate(),'Sue - check insurance')
commit
```

After the first transaction, I ran "select * from exam where accession = '[each of the two accession numbers]' and confirmed that the records were present in the table. But when I tried to run the second transaction, I got "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_*hold*_accession__20C1E124". The conflict occurred in database "MBMS_Track", table "dbo.exam", column 'accession'."

What am I missing?

Comment: Any `accession` values you trying to insert int HOLD table must exist in Exam table first, You have create a foreign key constraint to enforce this relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your key values don't match. In exam, your key values are 'RAM1093129' and 'RAM1093130', but in hold they are '1093129' and '1093130'. Make the values the same for both tables' accession columns, and see what happens.

Comment: It's Sizzle.  No, it's Sizzle Lean!

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the foreign key contraint.
you are inserting `RAM1093129` into exam (accession) column, but then using `1093129` in hold